# Saving specific symbol to file failed

Tags: python-3.x, file, save

I have a problem with my code

```
data='#Tk.Label(hl, text = "√((u¹)²+(u²)²)", font = "Arial 12").pack()'
file=open("File.txt", "w")
file.write(data)
file.close()
```

this code has some special symbols, such as √ , ¹ or ². When I try to save this string to file it raise this error:

`UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u221a' in position 22: character maps to <undefined>`

thanks for help.

Comment: Try adding the letter `u` in front of the `'` marking the beginning of the string

Comment: I am using python 3, so I can't use u"some text". I have that idea, but python 3 may have implemented Unicode, so I don't know where is the problem